# Como receber dados do formulário e informar no elemento div do formulário o resultado da soma no php?

Tags: php

Preciso fazer isso: 
Crie um formulário HTML com dois campos text um div para apresentação
dos resultados e um botão do tipo submit.
1 – Crie um script em PHP, que receba dados do formulário e informe no elemento div do
formulário o resultado da soma dos números

Eu tentei fazer mas está dando erro e eu não sei resolver pois sou iniciante na programação

HELP!!!!!

```
<body>
<div>
    <form action="../model/numeros.php" method="POST">

    Informe um número
  <input type="text" placeholder="Número" name="n1"><br>
    Informe outro número
  <input type="text" placeholder="Número" name="n2"><br>
  <input type="submit"></input><br>

    <b>Resultado da soma:</b>
</div>
<div>
    <?php
        require_once '../model/numeros.php';
        $o = new numeros();
        $dados=$o->Somar();
        echo $dados;
    ?>
</div>
```

Minha classe php:

```
<?php
//$n1=$_GET['n1'];
//$n2=$_GET['n2'];
class numeros{
    $n1=$_POST["n1"];
    $n2=$_POST["n2"];
    public function Somar()
    {

        $total=$n1+$n2;
        return $total;
    }
}
```

?>

Comment: qual é o erro que está a dar? tire o action do form

Answer (score -1):

Você não pode colocar o arquivo da classe no action, você tem que colocar o script que vai chamar a classe Numeros, nesse caso você vai chamar o proprio arquivo, e ai sim pegar os valores do $_POST e passar para a função de soma.

Segue um exemplo bem simples sem nenhuma validação:

Arquivo index.php

```
<?php
    include_once 'Numero.class.php';
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="pt-br">
<head>
    <title>Exemplo</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
</head>
<body>
    <form action="" method="post">
        <p>
            <label>Informe o primeiro número</label><br/>      
            <input type="text" placeholder="Primeiro número" name="primeiroNumero" value="">
        </p>

        <p>
            <label>Informe o segundo número</label><br/>
            <input type="text" placeholder="Segundo número" name="segundoNumero" value=""><br>
        </p>

        <input type="submit"></input><br>
    </form>
    <?php
        $post = filter_input_array(INPUT_POST);

        if (isset($post)) {

            $primeiroNumero = $post["primeiroNumero"];
            $segundoNumero = $post["segundoNumero"];

            $numero = new Numero();
            $soma = $numero->somar($primeiroNumero, $segundoNumero);
    ?>
            <br/>

            <div class="resultado-soma">
                O resultado da soma é: <?=$soma?>
            </div>
    <?      
        }
    ?>
</body>
</html>
```

Arquivo Numero.class.php

```
<?php
class Numero {

    public function somar($primeiroNumero, $segundoNumero) {
        $soma = $primeiroNumero + $segundoNumero;

        return $soma;
    }   
}
```

Comment: Acredito que não faça muito sentido você aplicar `isset` no retorno da função `filter_input_array`. Independente da entrada, a variável sempre estará definida e isso não garantirá que os índices utilizados dentro do `if` existam de fato.

Answer (score -1):

Pelo que vc postou parece que vai utilizar duas paginas.

Uma para o formulário e outra para a pagina PHP.

Se esse é o caso, então coloque na action do form  `../model/numeros.php`

Caso contrário, ou seja, vai utilizar um único arquivo, coloque o HTML e o PHP na mesma página do jeito que está abaixo.

**HTML**

```
<form action="" method="POST">
  Informe um número
  <input type="text" placeholder="Número" name="n1"><br>
  Informe outro número
  <input type="text" placeholder="Número" name="n2"><br>
<input type="submit"></input>
```

**PHP**

```
if (isset($_POST['n1'], $_POST['n2'])){
     echo "<b>Resultado da soma:</b><br><div>". ($_POST["n1"] + $_POST["n2"]) . "</div>";
}
```

Comment: Lembrando que `if ($_POST['n1'])` não é uma forma de verificar se o índice existe na variável global. O mais interessante é utilizar a função `isset` mesmo: `if (isset($_POST['n1'], $_POST['n2']))`

Comment: Só queria economizar uns bytes, :)

Answer (score -1):

Eu fiz usando 2 páginas, uma para o formulário (html) que vai receber os dados e imprimir o resultado, e outra para o script (php), que vai fazer o calculo.

formulario.php

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Formulário</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div>
        <form method="post" action="">
            <br>Número 1  <input type="text" placeholder="digite aqui..." name="t1"><br><br>
            Número 2  <input type="text" placeholder="digite aqui..." name="t2">
            <br><br>
            <input type="submit" value="Somar">
        </form><br>
        </div>
        <div><br>
            <?php

                if(isset($_POST['t1'])&&(isset($_POST['t2']))){

                    $n=$_POST["t1"];
                    $n1= $_POST["t2"];

                    require_once 'soma.php';
                    $res = new Soma();
                    $soma=$res->somar($n, $n1);

                    echo "A soma é: ".$soma;
                }
            ?>

        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Soma.php

```
<?php
class Soma{
    function somar($n,$n1){

        $res =$n+$n1;
        return $res;
    }

}

?>
```

Comment: Lembrando que uma forma alternativa a chamar a função `isset` para cada variável é você passar múltiplas variáveis para a função: `if (isset($_POST['t1'], $_POST['t2']))`